# Obtener listado de productos con IVA incluido

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo un modelo de productos con la columna precio y IVA
Como puedo obtener el precio final (con porcentaje de IVA incluido)
Sobre todo cuando hago algo como

```
\App\Producto::where('marca_id', 4)->paginate();
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que construyas la consulta de este modo:

```
$datos = Producto::selectRaw('precio * IVA AS PrecioFinal')
                  ->where('marca_id', 4)
                  ->get();
```

La columna nueva se llama, PrecioFinal y es calculada mediante la multiplicación del `precio` por el `IVA` dentro del método `selectRaw()`

Lo anterior solo te va a devolver el campo calculado; pero si necesitas todas las columnas *mas* la columna nueva calculada; deberías hacer lo siguiente

```
$datos = Producto::selectRaw('*, precio * IVA AS PrecioFinal')
                  ->where('marca_id', 4)
                  ->get();
```

Es decir dentro del método `selectRaw()` pasamos un `*,` que nos ayuda a indicar que traiga todas las columnas y aparte la que se va a calcular al vuelo

Comment: Gracias @shadow pero el IVA es un porcentaje, con decimales en algunos casos, voy a ver usando parte de te ejemplo si llego a obtener un resultado

Comment: pero aún siendo una cantidad con decimales debe funcionar, puesto que es una columna que se calcula al momento; dime si ya trataste de este modo y que error te da @DiegoG